# Dewalt radio power supply

Tags: identification, replacement

[image]

Can someone tell me what chip U2 is in this picture?

Comment: You're not giving much context to the part.

Comment: "4KP" might be a [linear regulator](https://smd.yooneed.one/code344b.html).

Comment: linear reg is likely with two decoupling caps next to the part